# Как поменять местами некоторые строки и столбцы матрицы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть матрица:

```
#    0, 1, 2
x = [
    [0, 1, 0],  # 0
    [1, 0, 1],  # 1
    [0, 1, 0]   # 2
]
```

Матрица представляет собой таблицу смежности графа.

Путём перестановок строк и столбцов нужно привести матрицу к виду:

```
I = [0, 1, 2]  # начальное положение строк и столбцов
P = [0, 2, 1]  # конечное положение строк и столбцов

#    0, 2, 1
x = [
    [0, 0, 1],  # 0
    [0, 0, 1],  # 2
    [1, 1, 0]   # 1
]
```

Ненулевые элементы могут быть где угодно.

Как реализовать это с помощью циклов?

Comment: уточните - вам надо, чтобы матрица имела ненулевые элементы только по правой и нижней границам?

Comment: вот это `#    0, 2, 1` задано?

Comment: `[[x[P[i]][P[j]] for j in I] for i in I]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
idx = [0, 2, 1] # новый порядок

x = np.array([  # приводим 2-м список в массив numpy
    [0, 1, 0],  # 0
    [1, 0, 1],  # 1
    [0, 1, 0]   # 2
])

res=x[idx]
res=res[:,idx]
```

res в таком случае будет:

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```